# Weird results from Gauss Jordan Elimination implementation in Rust

Tags: python, math, matrix, rust, linear-algebra

I tried to transcode this:

```py
#Python equivalent the Rust version was transcoded from by me

import numpy as np

M = np.array([[8, -8, -9, -1], [-10, 15, -9, -25], [-9, -1, 7, 3]], float)

if M[0][0] == 0:
    M[0] += 1

for j in range(len(M)):  # For each column
    if M[j][j] != 1:  # If the jth element of that column is not 1
        M[j] = M[j] / M[j][j]  # Then divide the row by that element

    for i in range(len(M)):  # For each row
        if i != j:  # If we are not at the row we want to have the pivot 1
            M[i] -= M[j] * M[i][j]

np.set_printoptions(precision=20)
display(M[:, -1])`
```

script for Gauss Jordan Elimination from Python to Rust:

```rust
fn main () {
    let mut m = [[8.0, -8.0, -9.0, -1.0], [-10.0, 15.0, -9.0, -25.0], [-9.0, -1.0, 7.0, 3.0]];
    
    if m[0][0] == 0.0 {
        for i in 0..m[0].len() {
            m[0][i] += 1.0;
        }
    }
    
    for c in 0..m.len() {
        if m[c][c] != 1.0 {
            for e in 0..m[c].len() {
                m[c][e] = m[c][e] / m[c][c];
            }
        }
        for r in 0..m.len() {
            if r != c {
            for e in 0..m[r].len() {
                m[r][e] -= m[c][e] * m[r][c]
            }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for element in m {
        for element_ in element {
            print!("{}", element_);
        }
        print!("\n");
    }
}
```

and it runs without errors or warnings. Yet the results are incorrect. The correct results are:

```
0.6303724928366758, -0.5501432664756454,  1.160458452722063
```

I think they might be getting rounded in the Rust Version, but with my limited knowledge of rust I can't tell why they're being rounded or if that's even the problem. Also, I'm new to Rust and was wondering if there's any better ways to write my code, because I had to implement a lot of the stuff python did for me myself in Rust

I already tried to append the .0 to the end of the numbers at the start to change them to a float type (which seems to have worked because I was getting errors when comparing them to integers), but I still get rounded results.

Comment: When you divide by `m[c][c]`, extract it to a variable first. Otherwise values after `c` in that row will not be changed (since you are just dividing by one). It looks like multiplying by `m[r][c]` would be similarly affected.

Comment: Your Python code won't work in general. Try ```M = np.array([[0, 1, 10], [1, 0, 20]], float)``` which should have a simple solution [20,10]. It's unclear why you are adding 1s across the top if M[0][0]==0, and you have plenty of scope for division by zero from a diagonal element.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problems kmdreko noticed, where the single elements were being overwritten in the middle of a loop, which are called `mjj` and `mij` below. I also changed the variable names to match the Python and fixed the printing.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut m = [
        [8.0, -8.0, -9.0, -1.0],
        [-10.0, 15.0, -9.0, -25.0],
        [-9.0, -1.0, 7.0, 3.0],
    ];

    if m[0][0] == 0.0 {
        for elem in &mut m[0] {
            *elem += 1.0;
        }
    }

    for j in 0..m.len() {
        let mjj = m[j][j];
        if mjj != 1.0 {
            for elem in &mut m[j] {
                *elem /= mjj;
            }
        }

        for i in 0..m.len() {
            if i != j {
                let mij = m[i][j];
                for col in 0..m[i].len() {
                    m[i][col] -= m[j][col] * mij;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for row in m {
        println!("{:.16}", row[3]);
    }
}
```

If you do more extensive matrix work in Rust, consider using [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/).

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sake, here is how you can do it using `ndarray`:

```rust
use ndarray::{array, s, Axis};

fn main() {
    let mut m = array![
        [8.0, -8.0, -9.0, -1.0],
        [-10.0, 15.0, -9.0, -25.0],
        [-9.0, -1.0, 7.0, 3.0],
    ];

    if m[[0, 0]] == 0. {
        let mut row0 = m.row_mut(0);
        // Or
        // let mut row0 = m.slice_mut(s![0, ..]);
        row0 += 1.;
    }

    for j in 0..m.len_of(Axis(0)) {
        let v = m[[j, j]];
        if v != 1. {
            let mut row = m.row_mut(j);
            row /= v;
        }

        for i in 0..m.len_of(Axis(0)) {
            if i != j {
                let subtract = &m.row(j) * m[[i, j]];
                let mut row = m.row_mut(i);
                row -= &subtract;
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{}", m.slice(s![.., -1]));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05c8e009a5dab7d5acf46c0f79d311c1).

It is a lot more similar to the Python version, but more verbose (similar line count to the primitive Rust version). This is because few constraints of Rust:

- Types cannot be mutably and immutably borrowed at the same time. So we are required to extract some expressions into variables (`v`, `subtract`).
- The `op=` shorthand operator can only be used on places, not method calls. So `m.row_mut(0) += 1.` isn't a valid statement, we need to extract `m.row_mut(0)` into a variable. This can be made one-liner by giving up on operator syntax sugar, using method calls: `m.row_mut(0).add_assign(1.)`.
- The indexing operator in Rust is not as flexible as in Python (it requires to return a reference), so slicing is done with a method.

Comment: `op=` can be used on method calls if you dereference the returned value (e.g. `*m.row_mut (0) += 1`): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=190b82e69b3a8b4bb45ce2c1470a3fdb)

Comment: @Jmb Not with ndarray, because slicing doesn't return a `Deref` type.